# Google Map with Api 3 not showing on mobile ie

Tags: google-maps, internet-explorer, mobile, google-maps-api-3

I've implemented a map with Google Api 3, which works fine on every browser, android and ios phones, too. But not on a windows 8.1 phone with mobile ie.
It isn't even displayed - just an empty page  :-(
I've searched in google and here, but found only posts from 2013 which says, that there is a problem with windows phones and GoogleMaps. But nothing newer. Do only me have this problem? Here's my code:

```
<!-- call api funktions -->
<script>
  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.2014, 8.5804 ),
      zoom: 16,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      scrollwheel: false,
      panControl: true,
      draggable: false
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
      mapOptions);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(50.2014, 8.5804 ),
      title:"Schmerzzentrum"
    });
    var contentString = '<div id="mapinfo_box" style="color:#666;max-width:280px;">'+
    '<h1 id="mapinfo_h1">Schmerzzentrum</h1>'+
    '<div id="mapinfo_body">'+
    '<p style="font-size:16px;margin-bottom:15px;">Rathausplatz 6 <br />61440 Oberursel (Taunus)</p>'+
    '</div>';
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', initialize);
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize)
</script>
```

I've tested some other pages with a GoogleMap on it and get a security warning from mobile ie. When i click "ignore and access page" nothing happens. on this page i get just: nothing. The code is implemented in a WordPress header.php.
Can anybody help?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be because of the style sheet.

According to [this website](http://www.easypagez.eu/maps/ieworking.html),

`IE needs to know the size of the map ensure that it has been set`

it should be something about the style sheet. But somehow I can not reproduce it. I make a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kylelam/eejmpta1/1/) from your code, I added the style sheet and somehow it works, so I guess that is probably the problem.

[image]